# Cannot Controls.Find a ComboBox inside a GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, groupbox

On my Visual C# Form application, I have a combobox inside a groupbox to help organize / look neat. However, once I put the combobox inside the groupbox, I am no longer able to find it by looping through all of the controls on my form.

For example, if I run this code with the Combobox inside the Groupbox I get a different result than if its outside the group box:

```
  foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
  {
       richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + contrl.Name;
  }
```

If the combobox is inside the groupbox, it won't find it.

I also noticed in the Form1.Designer.cs file that whenever I add the combobox inside the groupbox, the following line of code appears to the groupbox:

```
this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.myComboBox);
..
this.groupBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 39);
this.groupBox4.Name = "groupBox4";
... etc...
```

And this line will be removed:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.myComboBox);
```

If I try to edit it manually, it automatically switches back once I move the combobox back inside the groupbox.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Brian

Comment: What is the question? If you add a control to a container, it goes into the container's Controls collection.  Otherwise it would not be a container.  The WPF tag is tag spam if this is WinForms. Also the designer file warns against editing changing it that way.

Comment: @user1038885 Here in StackOverflow, when you find a post that answers your question, you can kindly click on check mark near the answer to mark it as accepted. While you can only accept one answer, when you reached 15 reputation score, you can vote for useful answers including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the answer. You can also vote for good questions. This makes questions and answers more useful for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you added combo box to group box, so it is added to `Controls` collection of group box and the designer generates this code:

```
this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.myComboBox);
```

So if you want to find the combo box programmatically, you can use this options:

- Why not simply use: `this.myComboBox` ?
- Use `var combo = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("myComboBox", true).FirstOrDefault();`
- Use `var combo = (ComboBox)this.groupBox4.Controls["myComboBox"]`

Also if you want too loop, you should loop over `this.groupBox4.Controls` using:

- `foreach(Control c in this.groupBox4.Controls) {/*use c here */}`
- `this.groupBox4.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList().ForEach(c=>{/*use c here */})`

Answer (score 0):

Just like the Form object, the Group object can hold a collection of controls. You would need to iterate through the Group control's controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

One more idea for getting at all or one ComboBox in a GroupBox, in this case groupBox1. Granted Resa's suggestion for using Find with FirstOrDefault would be best to access one combobox.

```
List<ComboBox> ComboBoxes = groupBox1
    .Controls
    .OfType<ComboBox>()
    .Select((control) => control).ToList();

foreach (var c in ComboBoxes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}

string nameOfComboBox = "comboBox1";
ComboBox findThis = groupBox1
    .Controls
    .OfType<ComboBox>()
    .Select((control) => control)
    .Where(control => control.Name == nameOfComboBox)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (findThis != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(findThis.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ControlCollections Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method, it has a parameter that will search the parent and its Children for your control.

```
ComboBox temp;
Control[] myControls = Controls.Find("myComboBox", true); //note the method returns an array of matches
if (myControls.Length > 0) //Check that it returned a match
    temp = (ComboBox)myControls[0]; //use it
```